# What was happening in the opening sequence of Ghostbusters: Afterlife?

Tags: plot-explanation, ghostbusters-afterlife

What was going on in the confusing opening sequence of Ghostbusters: Afterlife?

- A vehicle is being driven quickly, pursued by a creature
- The vehicle crashes and ends up in a tree
- A man (presumably Egon Spengler) tries and fails to use a ghost trap on the advancing creature at his house
- He shuts the door, gets out his PKE meter and sits in his chair
- Some sort of cloudy apparition rises up behind him but then seems to vanish in smoke without harming him

What would be the correct narration of these events?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to mention that he hides the ghost trap before he gets into that chair.

**Here is my take:**

Egon trapped one of the hounds, the **Keymaster**. And the other hound, the **Gatekeeper**, was hunting him to get the Keymaster back. When the big trap failed, Egon knew he's dead, so he hid the ghost trap and just sat down. The Gatekeeper then entered the house and killed him. The KPE-meter showed activity to indicate that Egon is now a ghost.

Someone might say "Why didn't the Gatekeeper possess Egon to look for the trap?" Well, the Gatekeeper can only possess a female body. To give birth to Gozer you need to "unite" a female and a male body / Soul. The Gatekeeper is female because the female reproductive system can be considered a gate through which one enters this world. The Keymaster is male because the male reproductive system can be considered a key to open this specific gate. So, the Gatekeeper cannot possess Egon because he's a man.

Comment: Amazing insight! I saw the original "Ghostbusters" when I was a kid so the supernatural birds and the bees aspect went over my head and I wouldn't have made that connection

Comment: @m1gp0z yeah, neither did I when I first saw the original as a child, even though it was very obvious. But as you said, you've got to know how that "child-generating-procedure" really works.